# Html form java maths"bedmas"

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've been having trouble getting into the javascript maths.
I'm lost with *BEDMAS* values would be ((150+500)*0.6)-25)=365"value1-4" how would I get an input like this to go into "artist cut"

will post my all of the code

```html
<body>

 <form name="submit-to-google-sheet" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
 <fieldset>
  <input name="Date" type="Date" placeholder="Date" >
  <input name="Client" type="name" placeholder="Client">
  <input name="Artist" list="artist" placeholder="Artist">
 <datalist id="artist">
  <option value="Clyde">
  <option value="Eazy">
  <option value="Ale">
  <option value="Andy">
  <option value="Jaz">
  <option value="Geust">
 </datalist>

  <input name="Percentage" id="%" type="number" min="0.4" max="1" step="0.1" placeholder="Percentage" >

  <input name="Depost" id="depost" type="number" placeholder="Depost">
  <input name="Daycost" id="daycost" type="number" placeholder="Daycost">
    <input name="Jaz Artist" id="jaza" type="number" placeholder="Jaz Artist" >
  <input name="Jaz House" id="jazh" type="number" placeholder="Jaz House">
 <br><br>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<br><br>
<br>
    <div class="loading js-loading is-hidden">
      <div class="loading-spinner">
        <svg><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="js-success-message is-hidden">
   <h1>Tattdatt Tattoo</h1>
   <button type="reset" onclick="output();">Math</button>
   <h3>ARTIST CUT</h3>
   <h4 id="artistcut">$$$ </h4>
   <h3>HOUSE CUT</h3>
   <h4 id="housecut">$$$ </h4>
  </div>
    <p class="js-error-message is-hidden">Error!</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwlQn8LAFp7gmY8ifWdr5sjUtb1CHi3Z2d2O06fDcYLm3YFCMrX/exec'
    const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']
    const loading = document.querySelector('.js-loading')
    const successMessage = document.querySelector('.js-success-message')
    const errorMessage = document.querySelector('.js-error-message')
    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      showLoadingIndicator()
      fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
        .then(response => showSuccessMessage(response))
        .catch(error => showErrorMessage(error))
    })
    function showLoadingIndicator () {
      form.classList.add('is-hidden')
      loading.classList.remove('is-hidden')
    }
    function showSuccessMessage (response) {
      console.log('Success!>', response)
      setTimeout(() => {
        successMessage.classList.remove('is-hidden')
        loading.classList.add('is-hidden')
      }, 500)
    }
    function showErrorMessage (error) {
      console.error('Error!', error.message)
      setTimeout(() => {
        errorMessage.classList.remove('is-hidden')
        loading.classList.add('is-hidden')
      }, 500)
    }
  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">

function output(){

 var value1 = document.getElementById('depost').value;
    var value2 = document.getElementById('daycost').value;
 var value3 = document.getElementById('%').value;
    var value4 = document.getElementById('jaza').value;
 var value5 = document.getElementById('jazh').value;

    document.getElementById('artistcut').innerHTML = parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2) * parseInt(value3) - parseInt(value4);
    document.getElementById('housecut').innerHTML = ((parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2)) * parseInt(value3)) - parseInt(value4);

}

</script>
</body>
```

everything else seems to be working alright, house cut will be working out the leftover value.

Comment: (150 + 500) * 0.6 - 25 = 365   Multiplication (*) and division (/) have higher precedence than addition (+) and subtraction (-)

Comment: no that dosent work, '

    document.getElementById('artistcut').innerHTML = parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2) * parseInt(value3) - parseInt(value4);
    document.getElementById('housecut').innerHTML = ((parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2)) * parseInt(value3)) - parseInt(value4);
}
</script>'

Comment: trying to fix the last part of the code, java ^^

Comment: "parseInt(0.6) = 0" bcoz parseInt for Integer values only. Not for the float. Try some thing like this var temp  = (parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2)) * parseFloat(value3) - parseInt(value4);

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code a bit. The problem you have encountered is that you are trying to turn everything into an integer ([parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)) when you are using floating point values and should be using [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). I have also renamed the values to make it clearer what is happening. As you can see, we can leave out brackets according to the BEDMAS principle which it seems you already know as shown in working out the artist cut or we can leave in the brackets to make it more clear as shown in working out the house cut.

```html
<body>

 <form name="submit-to-google-sheet" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
 <fieldset>
  <input name="Date" type="Date" placeholder="Date" >
  <input name="Client" type="name" placeholder="Client">
  <input name="Artist" list="artist" placeholder="Artist">
 <datalist id="artist">
  <option value="Clyde">
  <option value="Eazy">
  <option value="Ale">
  <option value="Andy">
  <option value="Jaz">
  <option value="Geust">
 </datalist>

  <input name="Percentage" id="%" type="number" min="0.4" max="1" step="0.1" placeholder="Percentage" >

  <input name="Depost" id="depost" type="number" placeholder="Depost">
  <input name="Daycost" id="daycost" type="number" placeholder="Daycost">
    <input name="Jaz Artist" id="jaza" type="number" placeholder="Jaz Artist" >
  <input name="Jaz House" id="jazh" type="number" placeholder="Jaz House">
 <br><br>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<br><br>
<br>
    <div class="loading js-loading is-hidden">
      <div class="loading-spinner">
        <svg><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="js-success-message is-hidden">
   <h1>Tattdatt Tattoo</h1>
   <button type="reset" onclick="output();">Math</button>
   <h3>ARTIST CUT</h3>
   <h4 id="artistcut">$$$ </h4>
   <h3>HOUSE CUT</h3>
   <h4 id="housecut">$$$ </h4>
  </div>
    <p class="js-error-message is-hidden">Error!</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwlQn8LAFp7gmY8ifWdr5sjUtb1CHi3Z2d2O06fDcYLm3YFCMrX/exec'
    const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']
    const loading = document.querySelector('.js-loading')
    const successMessage = document.querySelector('.js-success-message')
    const errorMessage = document.querySelector('.js-error-message')
    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      showLoadingIndicator()
      fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
        .then(response => showSuccessMessage(response))
        .catch(error => showErrorMessage(error))
    })
    function showLoadingIndicator () {
      form.classList.add('is-hidden')
      loading.classList.remove('is-hidden')
    }
    function showSuccessMessage (response) {
      console.log('Success!>', response)
      setTimeout(() => {
        successMessage.classList.remove('is-hidden')
        loading.classList.add('is-hidden')
      }, 500)
    }
    function showErrorMessage (error) {
      console.error('Error!', error.message)
      setTimeout(() => {
        errorMessage.classList.remove('is-hidden')
        loading.classList.add('is-hidden')
      }, 500)
    }
  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">

function output(){

 var depost = parseFloat(document.getElementById('depost').value);
    var daycost = parseFloat(document.getElementById('daycost').value);
 var percent = parseFloat(document.getElementById('%').value);
    var jaza = parseFloat(document.getElementById('jaza').value);
 var jazh = parseFloat(document.getElementById('jazh').value);

    document.getElementById('artistcut').innerHTML = (depost + daycost) * percent - jaza;
    document.getElementById('housecut').innerHTML = ((depost + daycost) * percent) - jazh;

}

</script>
</body>
```